# Is there a general method to find $\sum_{i = 1}^{N} i^a$

Tags: polynomials, gauss-sums, euler-sums

Is there a general method to find the sum of powers with negative exponent?

For example: $\sum_{i = 1}^{N} i^a$ with $ a \in \mathbb{Z} - \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Can you compute the harmonic numbers, namely the case $a=-1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the definition of the [generalized harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers). Assuming $a>0$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1 {i^a}=H_n^{(a)}$$

Comment: ah, thank you. Should have known that.